# Test multiple differences of means (multivariate t test)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean

Let's say I have a dataset with two groups (male and female), a target variable ($y$) and multiple features ($X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$).

| gender | y | X1 | X2 | X3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m | 100 | 39 | 150 | 12 |
| m | 120 | 44 | 180 | 16 |
| f | 100 | 22 | 140 | 14 |
| f | 150 | 40 | 169 | 20 |

I can test the hypothesis that the population means of $X_1$ are equal between men and women with a simple $t$ test.

$H_0$: $\mu_{X_1}^{m} = \mu_{X_2}^{f}$

$H_1$: $\mu_{X_1}^{m} \neq \mu_{X_2}^{f}$

I can carry out the same test for $X_2$ and $X_3$.

If I do this for every feature in my dataset, I will test each hypothesis **individually**. However, how can I test if all the population means are different between men and women **simultaneously**?

$H_0$:
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_{X_1}^m - \mu_{X_1}^f = 0\\
\mu_{X_2}^m - \mu_{X_2}^f = 0\\
\mu_{X_3}^m - \mu_{X_3}^f = 0
\end{bmatrix}

$H_1$: Any other case (at least one pair of means does not hold)

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for the [multivariate T test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution).

Comment: In your first null hypothesis you compare male mean of $X_1$ to female mean of $X_2$? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, but also the male mean of $X_2$ vs the female mean of $X_2$. So basically, using a multivariate distribution to simultaneously test those two hypotheses.

Comment: It sounds like Hotelling's $T^2$ test is exactly what you want, though I don't see how the target variable $y$ comes up.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't. I just added it to make the example more relatable.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to say what your problem is.